# Updating a range and keeping track of the maximum value that occurs at every index

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

> You are given an array, say A[], of N elements, initially all of them are equal to negative infinity.

Now you are asked to perform two types of queries(Total M queries):

> Type 1. Given two integers a and d you need to update the array A[] from index l to index r. What you need to do exactly is - for each index l+i (where 0<=i<=r-l) which contains some value say 'val' you need to update the value of that index with maximum of a+i*d and val, i.e, A[l+i] = max(A[l+i], a+i*d).

Type 2. Given an integer 'i', you need to report the value of A[i].

> Example : 
>   let N = 5 and M = 4

```
initially A[] = {-inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf}
query 1: l = 2, r = 4, a = 2, d = 3
new A[] = {-inf, 2, 5, 8, -inf}
query 2: i = 3
output = 5
query 3: l = 3, r = 5, a = 10, d = -6
new A[] = {-inf, 2, 10, 8, -2}
query 4: i = 5
output = -2
```

> Note : value of N and M can be as large as 100000 so I am looking for better algorithms than O(N*M).

Thanks.

Comment: You are given a homework assignment, say...

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, you are right. That's why I am looking for some hints only and not for the whole solution.

Comment: Hint: try doing stuff, see how far you get, and ask specific questions as they come up.

Comment: @Sneftel what I am thinking is to build a segment tree where I can update the ranges in log(N) time but updating a node itself is taking O(N) time, so I have no clue what to do.

Comment: @Sneftel: For these kinds of questions it's hard to even come up with an initial approach. Assuming this is the case with OP, I fail to see how he or she could have decomposed the problem into "specific" subproblems. I guess that's just a general problem with Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the problem this way: You are managing a collection of piecewise linear functions
 *f<sub>i</sub>(x) = a<sub>i</sub> x + b<sub>i</sub> (l<sub>i</sub> <= x <= r<sub>i</sub>)* subject to the following operations:

- Add a new function
- Find the maximum of all the functions added so far that are defined for a specific value of *x*

I see two possible approaches:

1. Store only the maximum ("upper hull") of all the functions, which is in turn a collection of piecewise linear functions, but with disjoint definition intervals. **UPDATE:** I initially thought this could be done with a simple binary search tree, but it's not as simple as that, so I would go with option 2
2. Follow a more standard approach and use a segment tree on the *x* range (the "array"), that stores sets of linear functions in its nodes. Now for a given *x*, you can walk up the tree to find out what linear functions are defined at that point and use the standard [convex hull trick](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Convex_hull_trick) to find their maximum at *x*. **Complexity**: *O(n + M * log n * log M)*

Comment: Also any (complete) tree you build is going to be **O(n)** to build it. It's searching trees that is **O(log n)**.

Comment: @aruisdante: Hah? Well I can build it in O(1) as well, but that's pretty irrelevant. Operations are `O(log^2 n)` for option 2 and `O(log n)` for option 1

Comment: You can build it in **O(1)** if you can predict what's going into it. You'd be hard pressed to build it for random data. Unless I read the problem wrong and the linear functions are evenly spread, in which case yeah it'd be **O(1)** to build

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't catch that you 'changed the base' for a lack of a better way to phrase it to make it the portion that is continuous so that you can do the array segmentation and make it **O(1)** to build.

Comment: How operations in option 2 can be done in O(logN*logM) ? I can't understand your solution completely. Lets say you are given 50000 update operations and 50000 query operation alternately(first update then query then update then query and so on) where all the update operation is from 1 to N. Then how does this solution handle this problem?

Comment: @NiklasB. As far as I know, it takes O(NlogN) to form a convex hull of N points so isn't this solution O(N*M) ?

Comment: @user113936: First you need to realize that there is a data structure that manages a collection of `k` general linear functions so that you can find out the maximum at a given point in `O(log k)`. The technique is described [in the Wiki article](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Convex_hull_trick#Fully_dynamic_variant). It has nothing to do at all with convex hulls of points, in fact convex hull trick is a pretty bad term. I like to call it "upper hull of a collection of linear functions". Now you have several instances of this data structure at each segment tree node and you get the runtime I claimed

Comment: Maybe option 1 is actually conceptionally a bit simpler. But I guess it is somewhat trickier to implement

Comment: @NiklasB. I think convex hull and convex hull trick are two different things, is it so ? Because I have no idea about "convex hull trick". That's why, probably, my question may be stupid ?

Comment: @NiklasB. I got your point. Thanks a lot to you :)